# Searching text in MongoDB with ReactiveMongo

Tags: mongodb, reactivemongo

I have some documents in MongoDB like the following:

```
{
  "no" : "ABC123",
  "description": "The brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"
}
```

I want to be able to search through all such documents in the collection and return all documents which contain, say, the word "fox" in the description. Is this possible with ReactiveMongo? Thanks

Comment: First try to "design" the query manually using the MongoDB Shell

Answer (score 4):

Actually, the problem you're trying to solve has nothing to do with `ReactiveMongo` as a driver.

For example, you can use `$regex` command to search string in mongodb like this:

```
def coll: JSONCollection = db collection "your_collection"

val nameToFind = "Andrey"
val query = obj("name" -> obj("$regex" ->  (".*" + nameToFind + ".*")))
coll.find(query).cursor[JsObject].collect[List]() map {
  case objects => Ok(obj("result" -> objects))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with the [$text](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#op._S_text) operator.